# Back to back tones for single character ˩˧ ˧˩?

Tags: tones

[image: yes]

> tian ˩˧ ˧˩

What do these back to back tones mean?

Tone sandhi?

book should be here: [book](http://nbct01.baidupcs.com/file/a04834fd03e33862ac150679edef1ee5?bkt=p2-nb-944&fid=521867496-250528-652496989958779&time=1462617078&sign=FDTAXGERLBH-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-GxPinMP7PgHO5VmJ%2BNNtsqHMoEI%3D&to=nbhb&fm=Nin,B,U,ny&sta_dx=22&sta_cs=0&sta_ft=pdf&sta_ct=6&fm2=Ningbo,B,U,ny&newver=1&newfm=1&secfm=1&flow_ver=3&pkey=1400a04834fd03e33862ac150679edef1ee55883d3650000015c6168&sl=76218446&expires=8h&rt=pr&r=198989889&mlogid=2963387329539921376&vuk=521867496&vbdid=3223180196&fin=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E9%82%9B%E5%B4%8D%E6%B2%B9%E6%A6%A8%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%A8%98.pdf&fn=%E5%9B%9B%E5%B7%9D%E9%82%9B%E5%B4%8D%E6%B2%B9%E6%A6%A8%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E8%A8%98.pdf&slt=pm&uta=0&rtype=1&iv=0&isw=0&dp-logid=2963387329539921376&dp-callid=0.1.1)

Comment: I guess this is not Standard Mandarin, but what is it then?

Comment: I'm not seeing tian ˩˧ ˧˩ in the text.  Instead it looks like tian ˩˧ + another mark which is not a standard tone letter. Non-standard markings should be explained in the front matter somewhere. What dialect is it?

Comment: This is from 《四川邛崃油榨方言记》，there are pdfs floating around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reversed tone letter is apparently one of the [Modifier Tone Letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_Tone_Letters) which do indeed indicate tone sandhi. I haven't yet come up with a pdf, but hazarding a guess, perhaps ˩˧ (low rising) is the recitation form and the reversed form is the sandhi form (low falling).

Comment: added a link for pdf in question, not sure if it works or not anymore.

Comment: Alas, no go for me.

Comment: This is a fairly common way to notate and represent tone sandhi, especially in linguistic papers and dictionaries in Chinese, e.g. [福州话方言词典](http://www.hxydw.com.cn/11587192.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

˩˧ is a contraction for ˩ ˧, that is an extra low tone followed by a mid tone.

Similarly, ˧˩ is ˧ ˩, a mid tone followed by an extra low tone.

Such tone combinations exist in Hmong.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_letter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmong_language

Comment: But that's two tones for one character....

Comment: Yes, so the character has two tones. Not uncommon. In Mandarin, 好 has hǎo, hào and hāo, for example.

Comment: Yeah, just like how the pinyin for 你好 is written nǐ hǎo hào hāo....

Comment: If not this, then it is a rising-falling tone, like the third tone in Mandarin, but opposite: ˨ ˩ ˦.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too but I think it would just be written in one fell swoop, like how you wrote the mandarin third time and not split in two.